# Hide BottomNavigation bar in Nativescript

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview

I am using Nativescript 7+ and I would like to hide the `TabStrip` on some pages after navigating to them. Below is my `.html` code.

```
<BottomNavigation id="bottomNav">
    <TabStrip>
        <TabStripItem iconSource="font://&#xf015;" title="title1" class="fa tabstripitem"></TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem iconSource="font://&#xf015;" title="title2" class="fa tabstripitem"></TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem iconSource="font://&#xf015;" title="title3" class="fa tabstripitem"></TabStripItem>
        <TabStripItem iconSource="font://&#xf015;" title="title4" class="fa tabstripitem"></TabStripItem>
    </TabStrip>

    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="outlet1"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="outlet2"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="outlet3"></page-router-outlet> 
    </TabContentItem>
    <TabContentItem>
        <page-router-outlet name="outlet4"></page-router-outlet>
    </TabContentItem>
</BottomNavigation>
```

I have tried using:

```
let bottomBar = <BottomNavigation>Application.getRootView();

if (bottomBar.android) {
    bottomBar.tabStrip.visibility = Visibility.hidden;
} else {
    bottomBar.viewController.tabBar.hidden = true;
}
```

However, `bottomBar.tabStrip.visibility = Visibility.hidden;` hides the whole tab (white page). I am testing in an android phone.

Answer (score 0):

use like that

```html
if (isAndroid) {
this.bottomNavBar.android.bottomNavigationBar.setVisibility(android.view.View.GONE)
} else {
     this.bottomNavBar.ios.tabBar.hidden = true;
}
```

Comment: Please share the declaration for ```bottomNavBar```. I have tried ```let bottomNavBar: BottomNavigation;``` or ``` let bottomBar = <BottomNavigation>Application.getRootView();````, I get the error ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'setVisibility' of undefined```.

Comment: give an id 
<BottomNavigation selectedIndex="0" id="bottomNavBar">
and use like this 
this.page.getViewById("bottomNavBar") as BottomNavigation;

Comment: ```android.view.View.GONE``` brings an error ```Cannot read property 'android' of undefined```. I cant seem to get it working even with ```@nativescript/types``` installed.